# NameValuePair error in Java

Tags: java

I am working on an API which calls the server through the REST method and I wrote this `getResponse` function for that but I am getting some error.

```
public static JSONObject getResponse(String url, Map<String, String> params, JSONObject object , String method)
  {
      JSONObject retObject = new JSONObject();

      params.put("organization_id", organizationId);
      params.put("authtoken", authtoken);

      Iterator<Entry<String, String>> paramsItr = params.entrySet().iterator();
      List<NameValuePair> nvpList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      while(paramsItr.hasNext())
      {
          Entry<String, String> param = paramsItr.next();
          nvpList.add(new NameValuePair(param.getKey(),param.getValue()));
      }
      NameValuePair[] nvpArray = nvpList.toArray(new NameValuePair[nvpList.size()]);

      if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET"))
          retObject = getRequest(url, nvpArray);
      else if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST"))
         retObject = postRequest(url, nvpArray, object);
      else
         retObject = deleteRequest(url, nvpArray);

      return retObject;
  }
```

The code is giving some error in this line :

```
nvpList.add(new NameValuePair(param.getKey(),param.getValue()));
```

The error is:

```
The constructor NameValuePair(String, String) is undefined
```

i have imported

```
import org.omg.CORBA.NameValuePair;
```

Comment: It's informing you that, there's no constructor of such type is defined. Check the class source or api and see how to build the required object

Comment: Which NameValuePair have you got imported?

Comment: Btw, If I am right, you must be using Apache HttpClient. NameValuePair is an interface and not a class.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you have imported `org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the imported NamevaluePair ,it should be from

```
         org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair
```

there are other namevaluepair available too as in

```
       org.omg.CORBA.NameValuePair
```

the namevaluepair in HttpClient has arguments as `String name,String value`
but in other namevaluepair the second argument might be different in other imports